# Why does the VC++ compiler MOV+PUSH args instead of just PUSH them? x86

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, compiler-construction, x86

In this disassembly from VC++ a function call is being made. The compiler MOVs the local pointers to a register before pushing them:

```
    memcpy( nodeNewLocation, pNode, sizeCurrentNode );
0041A5DA 8B 45 F8             mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
0041A5DD 50                   push        eax  
0041A5DE 8B 4D 0C             mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]  
0041A5E1 51                   push        ecx  
0041A5E2 8B 55 D4             mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-2Ch]  
0041A5E5 52                   push        edx  
0041A5E6 E8 67 92 FF FF       call        00413852  
0041A5EB 83 C4 0C             add         esp,0Ch
```

Why not just push them directly? ie

```
push  dword ptr [ebp-8]
```

Also, if you are going to do a separate push, why not do it manually. In other words, instead of doing "push eax" above, do

```
mov [esp], eax
```

Etc. the advantage of this is that after doing the 3 movs you can do a single subtract to set the new stack pointer, instead of implicitly subtracting three times with the pushes.

UPDATE---Release version

This is the same code compiled for release:

```
; 741  :    memcpy( nodeNewLocation, pNode, sizeCurrentNode );

  00087 8b 45 f8     mov     eax, DWORD PTR _sizeCurrentNode$[ebp]
  0008a 8b 7b 04     mov     edi, DWORD PTR [ebx+4]
  0008d 50       push    eax
  0008e 56       push    esi
  0008f 57       push    edi
  00090 e8 00 00 00 00   call    _memcpy
  00095 83 c4 0c     add     esp, 12            ; 0000000cH
```

Definitely more efficient than the debug version, but it is still doing a MOV/PUSH combo.

Comment: Is that actually compiled in release mode? It looks vaguely debuggish

Comment: It is compiled for debug. Why would that make a difference in this case?

Comment: Because the compiler is not going to care about such things in debug mode.

Comment: In your final example, is it safe to leave the stack temporarily unbalanced by deferring the sub?  I know that would be bad news in real mode (interrupt "borrows" part of your stack at an inopportune time), but I am not certain in protected mode.

Comment: By decoupling the instructions, you reduce the number of register stalls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured out the reason for it. It has to do with the way instructions are pipelined on the Pentium MMX. There are two pipelines, U and V, which allows MMX processors to process 2 instructions at a time ***IF*** they are pairable. PUSHs are not pairable with one another, but they are pairable with MOVs. So, if you write:

```
mov eax, [indirect]
mov esi, [indirect]
push eax
push esi
```

then, what happens is that instructions #1 and #3 get paired and #2 and #4 get paired so, effectively, these four instructions run in the same number of cycles as a single mov/push, and a single mov/push is faster than two push [indirect]s. This exact case is described in detail in Section 4.3, p. 41, Examples 4.11a and 4.11b, of the Microarchitecture optimization guide by Agner Fog, available widely on internet.

Comment: They actually wouldn't get paired here, because they had to be adjacent back in the PMMX. I would also be very surprised if MSVC is still optimizing for PMMX..

Answer (score 5):

This is an optimization.  It is explicitly mentioned in the Intel processor manuals, volume 4, section 12.3.3.6:

> In Intel Atom microarchitecture, using PUSH/POP instructions to manage stack space
>   and address adjustment between function calls/returns will be more optimal than
>   using ENTER/LEAVE alternatives. This is because PUSH/POP will not need MSROM
>   flows and stack pointer address update is done at AGU.
>   When a callee function need to return to the caller, the callee could issue POP instruction
>   to restore data and restore the stack pointer from the EBP.
>
> Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 19. (MH impact, M generality) For Intel
>   Atom processors, **favor register form of PUSH/POP** and avoid using LEAVE; Use LEA
>   to adjust ESP instead of ADD/SUB.

The rest of the manual isn't that clear about the reason, but it does mention a possible 3 cycle AGU stall on implicit ESP adjustments.

Comment: This is not really an Atom issue. I am using VS 10, the compiler for which was written before the Atom existed. Also, Atom is mostly a low-power architecture for notebooks and such.

Comment: It is a micro-architecture issue, Atom is just one chip of many that implements it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it only does it in debug builds, or possibly in some situations where it's warranted by pipelining or other considerations (e.g. it could put a parameter into `esi` and use it after the call). I've looked into some binaries, and MSVC definitely does use such pushes:

```
 push ebx          ; mthd
 push dword ptr [ebp+place+4]
 push dword ptr [ebp+place] ; pos
 push [ebp+filedes]   ; fh
 call __lseeki64_nolock
```

(code from the CRT)

As for the second question, instructions addressing `esp` are longer than pushes: `"push eax"` is one byte while `"mov [esp-8], eax"` is *four* bytes. In fact, this approach (`mov` instead of `push`) is used by GCC by default since a couple versions ago (option `-maccumulate-outgoing-args`) and it has led to [notable increases in code size](https://lkml.org/lkml/2007/7/29/100). Supposedly it makes code faster but I'm unconvinced.

Comment: I show the release build ASM, which has similar MOVs. In looking through the code for the project, the compiler never does an indirect push, only a MOV. My suspicion is that this may be to support a very old version of the x86 like an 286 or 386 or something.

Comment: @TylerDurden: Every x86 family member with 32-bit registers has also had "PUSH memory" instructions. But they are often slower to execute than a MOV-PUSH combination because modern microarchitectures don't really like instructions with more than one memory access.